# Handle a object like dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Hi everybody i have some issues with this code. I would to handle the class object diz like a dictionaries and implement the class with **add** method. In my code python runs a  syntax error at line 17. May someone help me? My final goal is to add and remove any quantity of fruit using **add** method.Sorry if i was wrong to post the question but it's my first posting here

```
class FruitBasket:
    def __init__(self,diz):
        self.diz = diz
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.diz)
    def __add__(self,frutto):
        self.frutto = frutto
        return self.diz[self.frutto] += 1

diz = {"banana" : 3 , "apple" : 5,"mango" : 1, "orange" : 2}

diz = FruitBasket(diz)

print(diz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do both `+=` and `return` in the same line

```
return self.diz[self.frutto] += 1
```

Instead you could do

```
self.diz[self.frutto] += 1
return self.diz[self.frutto]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a full dictionary-like behaviour (icluding indexing etc.) you can inherit from python dict:

```py
class FruitBasket(dict):
    pass


diz=FruitBasket()
diz = {"banana" : 3 , "apple" : 5,"mango" : 1, "orange" : 2}

diz = FruitBasket(diz)

print(diz)
# {'apple': 5, 'orange': 2, 'banana': 3, 'mango': 1}

print(diz['apple'])
# 5
```

This way it is de facto a dictionary but you can extend it with your own functionality.